# Laravel 4.2 .env.production.php not included

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

I have a strange issue with my Laravel 4.2 app.

I have two servers with DirectAdmin installed on both of them.

I use `.env.testing.php` on one, and `.env.production.php` on the second one.
First (testing) works fine, but on the second one the `.env.production.php` isnt handled at all.

I made a simple test and added `echo 'test';` in the file on both servers - and on production nothing happend and as I expected on testing 'test' word was displayed on the screen.

I'll be glad for any tips, sollutions - anything than might help with this.

And, yes the server is recognised as production one, yes I tried to use `putenv` and `getenv` to see if it is doing its job - both works fine.
And no I have no idea why it's not working :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: You may create a file for each environment supported by your application. For example, the development environment will load the .env.development.php file if it exists. However, the production environment always uses the .env.php file.

Comment: You are right - simple sollution :) rename file :) thanx a lot!